# Восстановить Ubuntu GRUB после установки CentOS (UEFI, GPT)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, grub, uefi

Установил на один диск на разные разделы Ubuntu 18.04 и CentOS 7.5. После установки CentOS система перезаписала существующий GRUB на свой и Ubuntu перестала грузиться. По советам в интернете я загрузился в LiveCD Ubuntu, и следуя [инструкции](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition) перезаписал груб. У меня структура разделов такая:

- sda1 (ESP)
- sda2 (Ubintu)
- sda3 (CentOS)

Соответственно с LiveCD я переписал sda1. После этого я загружаюсь в Ubuntu и получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сталкивался ли кто нибудь? Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Перед этим должен присутствовать текст ошибки. Неужто его нет?

Comment: ровно то что вывелось на экран. ничего не вырезано

Comment: Это странно. Без текста ошибки не понять, что не так. Тогда, наверно, остаётся только предложить пароль от root (если его нет, то установить через тот же LiveCD) и прочитать этот несчастный `journalctl -xb`